# Can Visual Studio Code Intellisense/Code Suggestions be Extended for User Defined Functions for Unsupported Languages? (LISP/AutoLISP)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way for VS Code to automatically suggest my defined function declarations based on the .LSP files present in the project? I understand that LSP language is not supported in terms of Intellisense. I have also tried using TabNine, but it doesn't recognize functions not located in the current file. I don't know how to get it to include other files in the project.

I am considering trying to create an extension that would scan the project .LSP files for function declarations and use the resulting matches as code suggestions. Would something like this be possible and how difficult would it be? (This is the first time I've ever messed with VS Code)

As of now, I am leaning towards writing a function that will add my functions to AutoDesks "alllispkeys.txt" which allows them to be suggested. This seems like a waste of VS Code's potential though, and it wouldn't limit the functions to only those defined in the project files.

Comment: If you cannot find an existing one and would like to write an extension of your own, you might get some hints from https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-write-your-language-server-in-c-d9302a44f694

Comment: Thank you Lex! Is that what I would be looking to create? A language server to extend the functionality of code suggestions for VS Code? I will have to look into it more.